# Lat/long transformed to OSGB has an offset when plotted

Tags: cartopy

If I take a set of lat/long points, convert them to OSGB crs using cartopy's "transform_points" method and then plot them, they are offset compared to plotting the lat/long directly. If I transform them back to lat/long, they plot ok. If I convert them to UTM coords they plot ok. Am I missing something?
Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.io.img_tiles import OSM

# set up figure and background map tile
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection=OSM().crs)
ax.set_extent((-2.473911, -2.410147, 50.567006, 50.605896))
ax.add_image(imagery, 14)

# Plot some test points using lat/long (PlateCarree) crs
test_lonlat = np.array([[-2.464482, -2.432523, -2.437892], [50.593243, 50.596390, 50.573177]])
plt.plot(test_lonlat[0], test_lonlat[1], 'r:+', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# Transform to OSGB coords and plot
test_OS = ccrs.OSGB().transform_points(ccrs.PlateCarree(), test_lonlat[0], test_lonlat[1])
plt.plot(test_OS[:, 0], test_OS[:, 1], 'kx-', transform=ccrs.OSGB())
plt.show()
```

Thanks for any advice.

### Simpler example using single point

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[7, 7])
ax = plt.axes(projection=OSM().crs)
ax.set_extent((-2.435, -2.405, 50.575, 50.595))
ax.add_image(OSM(), 14)

# Simpler test of OSGB crs
# Take point at end of outer breakwater: OS (370783, 76226) or lat/long (-2.414343, 50.584978)
point_os = [370774.0, 76221.0]
point_lonlat = [-2.414278, 50.584971]

# Plot each on OSM tile - both look ok but small error
plt.plot(point_os[0], point_os[1], 'r+', transform=ccrs.OSGB(), markersize=15)
plt.plot(point_lonlat[0], point_lonlat[1], 'kx', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), markersize=10)

# Convert lat/long to OSGB and plot - now offset by ~50 m to NW
point_os_new = ccrs.OSGB().transform_point(point_lonlat[0], point_lonlat[1], ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.plot(point_os_new[0], point_os_new[1], 'm^', transform=ccrs.OSGB(), markersize=10)

# Print both sets of OS coords
print(f'Original point: {point_os}')
print(f'Transformed point: {point_os_new}')
```

Comment: What is `imagery` in `add_image()`. It is not defined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an `axes` to plot with this line of code

```
ax = plt.axes(projection=OSM().crs)
```

you are expected to use `cartopy.crs.Mercator` projection coordinates to plot on it as OSM().crs is Mercator.

This part of your code:

```
# Transform to OSGB coords and plot
test_OS = ccrs.OSGB().transform_points(ccrs.PlateCarree(), \
    test_lonlat[0], test_lonlat[1])
plt.plot(test_OS[:, 0], test_OS[:, 1], 'kx-', transform=ccrs.OSGB())
```

uses OSGB coordinates to plot on Mercator projection. That's the wrong part.

The correct lines of code should be

```
test2_OS = OSM().crs.transform_points(ccrs.PlateCarree(), \
    test_lonlat[0], test_lonlat[1])
ax.plot(test2_OS[:, 0], test2_OS[:, 1], 'kx-', transform=OSM().crs)
```

[image: gb_south]

**Edit1**

The tile images in my plot above is `OSM()`, via `ax.add_image(OSM(), 14)`.
The problems the OP faces is not using matching coordinate systems between the data and the axes, or wrong values.

Comment: Thanks very much swatchai. And sorry - imagery should have been replaced with OSM().

Comment: I'm really trying to test converting a lat/long point to OSGB crs, then working in that crs with other points before plotting on the OSM tile. Your code converts my lat/long to OSM crs not OSGB. I've tried a simpler example where I've started with a point with OSGB and lat/long coordinates taken from the OS map and Bing maps. Plotting them directly shows they align with the expected point on the OSM map tile (red + and black x). Transforming the lat/long to OSGB and then plotting shows an offset of ~50 m to the NW (triangle). Code added to original post.